# Sina Weibo Authorization page

Tags: weibo, sinaweibo

I'm developing a Sina Weibo integration and I'm doing the oauth correctly but I have a problem with authorization page. When I click on enter, I accept authorization page and I can loggin correctly but if I log off and I try to clic another time enter, I can only see a login page, but no an authorization page.

How can I force that an authorization page shows always?

Answer (score 1):

The correct login flow consists of the following:
1. redirect user to the authorize page with the app's client id
2. client logs in to weibo (authentication)
3. client grants the application requested permissions (authorization)
4. client is redirected to your app page.

I believe the step you are asking about is #3. Once a user has granted your application permissions, this will be stored on their weibo account. The user will no longer be prompted to grant permissions every time the user logs in. The exception is when the user has removed your application from their weibo account. Thus there is no way for your application to force the user to reauthorize your app every time. It is unclear under what circumstances this would ever be required/beneficial.

As a side note:
If a user is already logged in, #2 is skipped by default. The user can be forced to relogin with the forcelogin parameter described in the docs: http://open.weibo.com/wiki/2/oauth2/authorize/en